# How to use Semantic UI with your existing Meteor Project?

Tags: javascript, meteor, user-experience, semantic-ui

I currently have a simple tutorial Meteor.js project running. How would I be able to skin this app using Semantic-UI? On their website they have html source code for individual forms and buttons, etc. I tried copying and pasting that into my own meteor project html file, but the entire application crashed and reported "Bad HTML formatting".

How can I resolve this situation and/or how do I easily skin my meteor project with Semantic-UI?

Comment: It's been several months since you asked. Any luck with this?

Answer (score 3):

**Install via Atmosphere**

Install the Semantic UI package from atmosphere:

`meteor add semantic:ui`

**Install the LESS AutoPrefixer**

You will need a special package less-autoprefixer, to add vendor prefixes to your LESS pipeline.

`meteor add semantic:ui flemay:less-autoprefixer`

Create a `custom.semantic.json` file
custom.semantic.json is a special file used to determine which themes and components to include in your project's build.

To remove a component from the pipeline, simply set the boolean value to `false`.

```
{
"definitions": {
  "accordion" : true,
  "ad"        : true,
  "api"       : true,
  /* etc */
},
"themes": {
  "amazon"     : false,
  "basic"      : false,
  "bookish"    : false,
  "bootstrap3" : false,
  "chubby"     : false,
  "classic"    : false,
  "default"    : true,
  /* etc */
}
```

**Start Meteor / Generate**

Every time Meteor starts or refreshes it calls the package `semantic:ui` to generate Semantic UI.

The package has a uses the diff between custom.semantic.json and `.custom.semantic.json` to avoid regenerating files unnecesssarily.

If the file `.custom.semantic.json` does not exist or it is different than `custom.semantic.json` then it will generate Semantic UI.

**Customize Site Variables**

Semantic UI meteor includes a site theme, `site/` which can be used to customize less variables for your site. These files are optional, and can safely be removed if customization is not necessary.

Visit our theming guide to learn more about theming.

**Issues & Debugging**

For help with Semantic UI Meteor, and for the latest updates, please visit the repository home on GitHub at https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-Meteor.

**FYI**: You may view these instructions in their context of origin on the SemanticUI Integrations page at http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/integrations.html#meteor

**Or Better Yet, THIS:** https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-Meteor/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

You can do that fairly easily by adding this package: https://atmospherejs.com/semantic/ui

```
meteor add semantic:ui
```

And that will include the necessary JavaScript and CSS files so that you can use the semantic-ui library.

Comment: Even when I do that and run the application, it crashes. Not sure what to do about that...

Comment: What is the error you are getting from the crash?

Comment: `nooitaf:semantic-ui` is deprecated. Use https://atmospherejs.com/semantic/ui instead.

Comment: `meteor add semantic:ui`